# Android Studio & ProGuard: cannot resolve symbol getDefaultProguardFile?

Tags: android, android-studio, proguard, android-gradle-plugin

**IDE**: Android Studio 1.1.0

**Subject**: ProGuard

**Problem**: ProGuard files or tools not recognized by Android Studio, `getDefaultProguardFile` *can not be resolved* and there's no `proguard-android.txt` and `proguard-rules.txt` files in the app, see the image below: (from build.gradle)

[image: build.gradle screenshot]

**How to fix this and achieve ProGuard protection to my App ?**

Comment: Hi.

It seems like the default filename generated by Android Studio is proguard-rules.pro. The one showing in your gradle file is proguard-rules.txt. It could just be the filename.

Comment: Try rebuilding your project, then sync the project with the gradle files.

Comment: i did, still the same

Comment: I'm using Android Studio 1.5.1.
In my case works like a charm.
Please could you post your *dependencies {...}*?

Comment: Cutting and pasting the code from and back to the same location eliminated the error warning for me. I had same issue/fix for 'signingConfigs'. It never prevented me from compiling, so maybe it was a false positive, at least in my case.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to change into -

```
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
```

Comment: I did, it's not working actually `Android Studio` not recognizing the method `getDefaultProguardFile`

Comment: @FadiObaji do you have "proguard-rules.pro" file under app folder?

Comment: make sure you have this line at the top of your gradle file" apply plugin: 'com.android.application'"

Comment: Yes it's there, still no luck, i think if i deleted the `tools` folder from the sdk folder and then re-download it will fix the problem, because i copied the entire `SDK` folder from another windows

Comment: could be a cause. Best of luck at your journey :|

Comment: Have you guys found any solution to this? I've wasted 2 days for searching and figuring out solution for this.

Answer (score 8):

I had the same trouble as shown here:

[image]

The error message makes it seem as if the file is not being found, and therefore not read.  However, I went to into sdk/tools/proguard folder to find the file, and at the top added a statement to test if the file was actually being read. I put at the top "Will this crash it?"

[image]

As you can see from the error, the file was indeed found during the build process and the statement I added crashed it.  Thus, it appears the "can't resolve symbol" error is giving a false positive.

Answer (score 4):

I really had the same issue. So here is what made my project working:

```
release {
    minifyEnabled true
    proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Tested by this code:

```
 Log.d(TAG, "TEST!");
 Log.i(TAG, "INFO!");
 Log.e(TAG, "ERROR!");
```

In proguard.pro I placed this snippet (which removes all `Log.d`-Statements in the byte-code)

```
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static int d(...);
}
```

And the cat says:

```
MainAct﹕ INFO!
MainAct﹕ ERROR!
```

-> exactly what I tried to achieve :)

PS: This assumes that you have the `proguard.pro` file in the module (aka 'app') folder.

Comment: Actually when i made a `signed apk` everything worked fine and i de-compiled the file to see if `proguard` worked and it did work, i don't know why `android studio` says `can not resolve symbol`

Comment: Ohh, nice. In my situation (hiding the Logs), AS will only run the proguard config if I set the file as I wrote it above.

Comment: i think `proguard` removes all `logs` from your apps without telling it to do so, it's in the `proguard` description

Comment: this shouldn't be the default-behavior.. (AFAIK)^^

Comment: What about the other methods something like `options.compilerArgs` ? also i have `cannot resolve symbol options`

Answer (score 1):

Try:

`proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-android.txt'))
 proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules.txt'))`

This structure works in the **gradle-experimental** plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue of Android Studio not recognising the method by using double quotes instead of the single. The below is what I ended up using:

```
    release{
        shrinkResources true
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
{
  minifyEnabled false
  // proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro' 
  proguardFiles 'proguard-rules.pro'
}
```

Answer (score -7):

In my case:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        runProguard false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

replace `runProguard false` with `minifyEnabled false` works.

Comment: `minifyEnabled false` will disable ProGuard obfuscation