# App crashing with release apk [Android Studio]

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, apk, proguard

For my android project, I was building release apk(s) till now and the generated apk(s) successfully opened when launched. Today suddenly, I started getting the following exception on building the release apk after making a small change to the app. Here is the exception:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.AssertionError: impossible
       at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:45)
       at java.lang.Enum$1.create(Enum.java:35)
       at libcore.util.BasicLruCache.get(BasicLruCache.java:54)
       at java.lang.Enum.getSharedConstants(Enum.java:211)
       at java.util.EnumSet.noneOf(EnumSet.java:48)
       at java.util.EnumSet.allOf(EnumSet.java:66)
       at com.facebook.internal.SmartLoginOption.(SmartLoginOption.java:29)
       at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.parseAppSettingsFromJSON(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:225)
       at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager.access$000(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:53)
       at com.facebook.internal.FetchedAppSettingsManager$1.run(FetchedAppSettingsManager.java:143)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

I read a few posts ([this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51693786/why-the-build-process-ignore-proguardfiles-getdefaultproguardfileproguard-andr) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29527524/android-studio-proguard-cannot-resolve-symbol-getdefaultproguardfile)) regarding this crash and some of them pointed to check if the `proguard-android.txt` (inside `<myhome>/Library/Android/sdk/tools/proguard`) is properly getting read or not. So, I wrote some random sentence at the top of this file and re-ran the code. But, it successfully ran. I tried cleaning cache as well. Finally, I decided to reinstall Android Studio. And after a clean install of Android studio as well ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17625622/how-to-completely-uninstall-android-studio-on-mac)), I still face the same issue. I am stuck here for almost 5 hours now and want some help. If anyone has any pointers, please do help me.

The code snippet from my gradle file is:

```
....
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'

        }
    }
....
```

Comment: change minifyEnabled true in the debug release and run the app, you'll get to know the error. This must be due to proguard. update your proguard rules accordingly

Comment: @TarunKumar, thanks for the suggestion. I tried and I get the same crash log with the debug build as well.

Comment: @Swapnil I am facing the same issue. Did you figure out a solution?

Comment: @gpasse Upgrading to a newer libary version helped me.